# Adding date to database from Paddle webhook payload (Laravel)

Tags: laravel, database, paddle-paddle

I'm building this with Wave, which is just kit type thing that implements a few things that you need to get a SaaS off the ground quickly...one of the things it has configured is Paddle. Unfortunately it does not have an option to where if a user cancels their membership, it allows them to finish out their paid period instead of removing access right away. So I'm trying to add this. I can see in the Paddle docs that the id for this in a received webhook payload is  cancellation_effective_date. Here is the relevant bit of the cancel button function that I'm adding to:

> private function cancelSubscription(  $subscription_id){
> $subscription = PaddleSubscription::where('subscription_id',         $subscription_id)->first();
> $subscription->cancelled_at = Carbon::now();
> $subscription->status = 'cancelled';
> $subscription->save();

I've tried splicing in both of these, just trying to deduce the syntax but I'm wrong, and I can't figure out why. It said I need to define the variable when I do this, but I cannot figure out how to do this.

> $subscription->cancellation_effective_date = $request->cancellation_effective_date;

> $subscription->cancellation_effective_date = $cancellation_effective_date;

Any suggestions?

Here is the full file if anyone needs to see it. https://github.com/thedevdojo/wave/blob/main/wave/src/Http/Controllers/SubscriptionController.php

Here is a sample payload return from Paddle

> Array
> (
> [alert_id] => 1282370466
> [alert_name] => subscription_cancelled
> [cancellation_effective_date] => 2023-04-10
> [checkout_id] => 9-d11a2ef3289d6c8-ccdeb4a3ad
> [currency] => EUR
> [custom_data] => custom_data
> [email] => irunolfsdottir@example.net
> [event_time] => 2023-04-05 20:13:54
> [linked_subscriptions] => 7, 2, 7
> [marketing_consent] => 1
> [passthrough] => Example String
> [quantity] => 18
> [status] => deleted
> [subscription_id] => 6
> [subscription_plan_id] => 8
> [unit_price] => unit_price
> [user_id] => 1
> ]

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

here is how i would do it:

-first make a migration to add a column (cancellation_effective_date) to the subscription table

-then override the SubscriptionController class, specifically the public webhook method and the cancelSubscription method, the latter will become:

$this->cancelSubscription($subscription_id, $request->cancellation_effective_date);

now you are ready to save the effective date to the db.